# Можно ли такой sql запрос перевести на Criteria Api?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Не так давно начал изучать Hibernate, а вместе с ним и Criteria API.
Возникла необходимость выполнить такой SQL запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users RIGHT JOIN user_group ON users.id = user_group.userId WHERE user_group.groupId = 'идентификатор группы' ORDER BY users.cash DESC;
```

Но создать его рабочую версию с помощью Criteria Api никак не получается. Возможно ли создать такой запрос с помощью Criteria Api? И если да, то был бы очень благодарен за пример структуры такого Criteria Api запроса.

Модель User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "userName", length = 32)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "firstName", length = 128)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName", length = 128)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "cash", nullable = false)
    private int cash = 100;
```

Модель UserGroup:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_group")
public class UserGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "groupId", columnDefinition = "BIGINT", length = 20)
    private long groupId;
```

Я не понимаю как правильно создать join, а поиски в сети не дали желаемого результата:

```
public List<User> getTopUsersInGroup(long groupId, int limit) {
        Session session = SessionConfigurator.getSession();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> r = cq.from(User.class);
        Join<User, UserGroup> join = r.join(// ???);
        cq.select(r);
        // ???
        cq.orderBy(cb.desc(r.get("cash")));
        return session.createQuery(cq).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Покажите что получилось у вас, а там возможно уже сможем вам помочь

Comment: @DmitryD Дополнил пост внизу.